# Categories in which every monomorphism is regular / effectivie?

Tags: category-theory, universal-algebra, monads

I'm interested in conditions on a category of modules of a monad on a topos satisfies the property that

- Every monomorphism is the equalizer of its cokernel pair.

Every topos itself satisfies this property, and some varieties of algebras do as well (for example, groups, and commutative idempotent monoids).

I'm wondering about general conditions under which this holds.

Comment: Sounds pretty general already

Comment: I am particularly interested in whether (sheaves of) modules for an idempotent semiring satisfy this property.